# What collective chat program can feature both the host's webcam AND his screenshare?

Tags: fate, tools, online-roleplaying, tool-recommendation

Most options I've looked at are either too complicated to get new people into, or can only accept **one stream per participant**. I'm the GM, I need both my face AND a screen share for the aspects and a basic map.

I don't need a special facility for that, I'm ok with just being able to stream a Powerpoint window for the aspects (Fate RPG) or something, but I need at least two streams. Any options for me?

Answer (score 9):

Google hangouts. Invite yourself twice, mute one instance.

When I've presented at conferences, remotely, I've driven two instances of google hangouts in exactly this way. So long as you've got one of the instances' audio completely cut out (I recommend the screenshare), and enough bandwidth to push both, you're just fine.

You have to use multiple google accounts (but who doesn't have multiple accounts) set in different sessions of chrome. When I presented (and tested just now) it also requires the primary initiator to be either in a hangouts on air (you don't have to broadcast, but it turns on broadcaster tools to mute participants) or choose a moderated video call -- whatever means (and it changes every few months) to get to the [control room app](http://www.googleplusdaily.com/2013/12/moderate-hangouts-on-air-with-new.html).

Hangouts also features google drive, google slides, and [rizzoma](http://rizzoma.com) integration, which may reduce the need for dual-channel screen sharing. You may also find a hangouts app that serves your purpose, though I've had poor experiences with most, save for drawing a beard over my beard (which was amusing.)

Comment: Should also note that roll20 is also useable with this setup

Comment: What if he has not enough bandwidth? I'd use google documents instead of the powerpoint file

Comment: I've found roll20 to be annoying via hangouts, but if you've derived utility from it in this way, I encourage your own answer.

Comment: Can you please help me out a bit? How do I add multiple instances of myself? It says I'm already there, unsurprisingly...

Answer (score 4):

Skype allows multiple streams; I use it to tutor my brother, who lives far from me, and he shares both his screen (so I can see what he's working on) and his webcam (so I can see his face). Recently, they added multiple video chat, but I've never used it with the screen-sharing function so I'm not 100% sure it will allow both multiple recipients and two streams. Still, it ought to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at zoom (zoom.com) but it does cost a little money.  It works fairly nicely as I use it for business.  Although I rarely use the chat typing functionality and opt for the microphone.  It does have one however.

Answer (score 0):

A simple DIY solution might be to just stream your desktop, but also run a program that displays your webcam in a window on your desktop. Then you can toggle between windows as needed, or possibly even find a way to pin the webcam view on top of the other windows.

Edit: I don't know what OS you're using, and you can Google as easily as I can, but a quick search shows that one such program for Windows 7 is called [WebcamViewer](http://www.bustatech.com/webcamviewer-a-simple-viewer-for-webcam/).

Comment: Note: When sharing your whole screen, beware of the recursive video effect. That's when you bring up the image of your desktop in an app window on your desktop. The cascade of endless images updating within images can be difficult to get out of on some systems.